# WEB 3...BLOCKCHAIN...SMART CONTRACT

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test my smart contract named mobolaji using "npx hardhat test" and it is giving me error message like

"  mobolaji contract
1) "before each" hook for "Should update balances after transfers"

9 passing (4s)
1 failing

1. mobolaji contract
   node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\artifacts.ts:516:21)
   at Artifacts.readArtifact (C:\Users\User\Desktop\hardhat\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\artifacts.ts:71:26)
   at getContractFactory (C:\Users\User\Desktop\hardhat\node_modules@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:107:22)
   at Context. (C:\Users\User\Desktop\hardhat\test\Mobolaji.js:16:17)"

can anyone help with suggestions please?

I tried using chatgpt but it is not working out either